# How to split in R a date range into quarterly basis period?

Tags: r, date

I want to split monthly date range into quarterly basis period.
My Date Variable is built with as.yearmonth:

```
> data$DATES
jul. 2014 
ago. 2014
sep. 2014
...
...
jun. 2016
jul. 2016
ago. 2016
sep. 2016
```

How should I do it? cut function works with dates? I don't want to do this manually.

Comment: This question needs to have input data in reproducible form and illustrative output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lubridate has a quarter function. Check it out:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd(c("2012-03-26", "2012-05-04", "2012-09-23", "2012-12-31"))
quarter(x)
quarter(x, with_year = TRUE)
```

Then the only thing you have to do is sort out your date formats so that they are understood.

Comment: Finally I use semester function, and it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming by yearmonth you meant `"yearmon"` class from zoo as per Note at the end:

**1) yearqtr** Convert to `"yearqtr"` class (also in zoo, like `"yearmon"`) and split on that. No additional packages beyond those you are already using are needed.

```
split(data, as.yearqtr(data$DATES))
```

or if you want to aggregate it, rather than split it:

```
aggregate(values ~ DATES, transform(data, DATES = as.yearqtr(DATES)), mean)
```

**2) cut** If you want to use `cut` then:

```
split(data, cut(as.Date(data$DATES), "quarter"))
```

**Note:**  Test data in reproducible form:

```
library(zoo)
data <- data.frame(DATES = as.yearmon(2014) + 0:11/12, values = 1:12) # test data
```